# Adding custom dimensions in GA4 means event count decreases

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

When I add a custom dimension to an exploration checking pdf downloads the event count decreases. The custom dimension provides information on what unit the pdf download was for and you can see some are filled in and also some are not set.
Why does adding this change the results? It means we cannot pull data using this custom event. Also this was not always the case and we did not see this before when pulling data from the api.
I attach 2 images showing 1 with the Custom Event called Unit added and the other without.
[image]

[image]

Comment: One potential issue is that the unit dimension may not be compatible with the session_start event, which provides session source data for GA4. If you try to use them together, it can result in some undefined rows and cause the sum of events to be inaccurate. Therefore, it's best to avoid using them together .